# Qt5 Compiler Error: 'QtQuick': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

I created a Qt-GUI-Application, in which I want to embed a QtQuick 2.0 QML file.
For that matter I added QT += quick in the .pro file

this is what my code looks like:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtQuick>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QQuickViewviewer;
    viewer.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("file.qml"));
    viewer.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But all I get is the following error message as soon as I want to built it:

..\main.cpp:3: Error:C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtQuick': No such file or directory

How can I solve this?

I'm using Qt 5.1.1 on Windows 7

Edit:
This is how the .pro file looks like

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-10-15T17:54:42
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui \
            quick

TARGET = IntegratedPowerSupply
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS  +=

OTHER_FILES += \
    ../../PowerSupply/PowerSupply/file.qml
```

Comment: Thats a compile error, not a linker error. Specifically a preprocessor error.

Comment: It means that you don't have QtQuick.h in your include directories. Find for this file and add proper dir to project settings

Comment: I searched my entire Qt directory but there's no QtQuick.h

Comment: So you didn't build it.  Take a look here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-index.html

Comment: But I already deployed QML Applications with QtQuick 2.0.. For example with the Qt Creator -> QtQuick 2 UI.. That worked perfectly fine

Comment: So I found a file called "QtQuick" without any fileextension. But it seems to be the header. Still the same error though. How can I add it to the project setting?

Comment: The solution to such problems is *always* the same: 1. Remove the build directory. 2. Build your project.

Comment: Besides, it's kind of silly not to post the project file when the whole discussion revolves around it. Edit your question and add the contents of the `.pro` file.

Comment: Hi Kuba. I already tried that. The error stays the same. I also posted the .pro file

Comment: I think I got it.. had to change the includes to QGuiApplication and QQuickViewer, then I got some Linker Error which I resolved by restarting the Creator and it worked..

Comment: @PogoMips Post your solution as an answer and accept it, if it solved your problem.